# Access numeric properties of an object using dot notation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Why can’t we access this array-like object’s properties with dot notation instead of bracket notation?

```js
function testArray(rat){
  return typeof arguments;
}

console.log(testArray("test")); // "object"

function testArray(rat){
  return arguments.0; // `arguments[0]` works.
}

console.log(testArray("test")); // Throws error.
```

Comment: [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is _"an **Array-like object** corresponding to the arguments passed to a function."_ And, no... you can't access the n-index properties via dot notation.

Comment: Related: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](/q/4968406/4642212) and [Can I get a javascript object property name that starts with a number?](/q/5809790/4642212). There’s also [Why javascript array element can't be accessed with dot notation?](/q/31302956/4642212) which asks about the rationale of these parsing rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems to be about why we can’t access array and array-like elements using the dot notation like this:

```js
const v = a.0;
```

It’s described [in the ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors):

> The dot notation is explained by the following syntactic conversion:
>
> *MemberExpression* `.` *IdentifierName*

And identifiers may not start with a digit [as described here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-names-and-keywords):

> *IdentifierName* ::
>
> *IdentifierStart*
>     *IdentifierName IdentifierPart*
>
> *IdentifierStart* ::
>
> *UnicodeLetter*
>     `$`
>     `_`
>     `\` *UnicodeEscapeSequence*

As for the reasoning, having identifier names just being made of digits would have made it difficult to write number literals. An exception could probably have been designed just for array access but that would have made the language more complex and departing from the common C family syntax without any real gain.

Answer (score -1):

You can:

```
var arr = [];
arr.foo = 'foo';

console.log(arr.foo); // => 'foo'
```

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Sure, but it was a hard trip :)

Comment: I doubt it. It doesn't look like a pertinent use of an array-like object.

Comment: @dystroy Of course! But his question left me alone with my brain, and that's the result ;)